# android:list view with thumbnail

Tags: android, image, android-listview

I need to create the list view of video's with it thumbnail images.The image name come from the database.I can give value to textview but when try to give value to image view it crash also in bitmap

```
        class CustomSimpleCusorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    //TextView title;
    public CustomSimpleCusorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {

        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.layout=layout;
        this.context =context;

    }

public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

     LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      View view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

     return view;
    }
@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

    Log.d("DATABAT",c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.VIDEO_TITLE)));
    Log.d("DATABAT",c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.VIDEO_IMAGE)));

    TextView section_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
    section_text.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.VIDEO_TITLE)));
    ImageView thumb =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.icon);
  //         
    String filename = "flag_1";
      int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(filename, "drawable", context.getString(R.string.package_str));
  Log.d("ID",""+id);

  thumb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menuicon);

}

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay ... treading lightly here, but this sounds exactly like the problem my buddy had when trying to display the thumbnails for his videos app ...

Here's an [Encode/Decode tutorial for base64](http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html)

And just for reference; here's the link to his app in the market (300,000+ downloads): [Video Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.androidcodemonkey.videos.free)

Answer (score 1):

Try this where

```
 String urldisplay=img_value.toString();
 InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
 mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new PatchInputStream(in));
 mIcon11=ImageHelper.getRoundedCornerBitmap(mIcon11,30);
 holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mIcon11);
```